# jQuery - function to pass in multiple window size parameters

Tags: jquery

I can't quite figure out the best way to do this. I've got multiple conditionals that 
looks at the browser width and does something with it based upon the window size.

```
$.fn.browserWidth = function() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1024) {
  //do something
  }

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 1000 && document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 700)  {
  //do something
  }

  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth <= 450) {
  //do something
  }
};
```

There are more cases for this I just showcased 3. What I would like to do is be able to easily
pass in width parameters in another file and do something along the lines of.

```
if(browserWidth(900)){
   //dos something.
}

if(browserWidth(400)){
   //do something
}
```

Maybe I'm just over thinking this but I've been banging my head for hours on this. Please include
code samples as I learn best that way. Thanks!

Comment: So you don't know how to define functions with parameters? Don't despair! `=>` http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired example, you could define a function that takes a `width` parameter and returns `true` or `false` depending on the browser width.

```
function browserWidth(width) {
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth <= width;
}

if (browserWidth(900)) {
    // do something.
}

if (browserWidth(400)) {
    // do something
}
```

By the way - if you're using these browser width conditionals in order to manipulate content on the page, check out [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but how would this work if I'm checking if the width is greater than, like in my first conditional in the function.

Comment: @Delmon: You could define the function to accept two arguments, a min width and a max width. Then you could handle the cases where only one argument is given differently. I mean, it's not really clear what you expect to test if you just pass `900` to the function. In your first example you use 4(!) different numbers for the comparison. How did you expect this to be reduced to one number?

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks for the advice. I should have been clearer in my description ideally I'd like to do what you suggested and be able to see if the browser width is less than a number or greater than a number, just wasn't clear in the description.